# Mobile viewport is using the tablet viewports CSS

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

**My mobile viewport is not picking up the CSS for the default/mobile vieport. Instead, it is using the tablet viewports CSS. I am using twitter-bootstrap media-queries to separate the CSS between the different viewports. Research has led me to no clue what could be causing this problem other than something going wrong in the rails asset pipeline maybe?**

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>TimelessAngularRails</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application'%>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid js-menu-dd-container">
      <div class="row js-menu-dd">
        <div>
          <a href="/"><h4 class="nav-menu-dd-text">Home</h4></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="/about"><h4 class="nav-menu-dd-text">About</h4></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="/procedures"><h4 class="nav-menu-dd-text">Procedures</h4></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="/for_men"><h4 class="nav-menu-dd-text">For-Men</h4></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="/vip"><h4 class="nav-menu-dd-text">Vip Membership</h4></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="/international"><h4 class="nav-menu-dd-text">International</h4></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="/media"><h4 class="nav-menu-dd-text">Media</h4></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="/location"><h4 class="nav-menu-dd-text">Location and Directions</h4></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row nav_row text-center">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
          <span class="nav_glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify js-menu-button"></span>
          <p class="nav_text js-menu-button">Menu</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
          <a href="/contact"><span class="nav_glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
          <p class="nav_text">Contact</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
          <a href="/blogs_home"><span class="nav_glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
          <p class="nav_text">Blog</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
          <a href="/gallery"><span class="nav_glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span>
          <p class="nav_text">Gallery</p></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row border_under_nav"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row text-center main_logo_phone_number_row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-6">
          <img class="application_page_main_logo" src="/assets/timelessEstheticsMainLogo.jpg">
          <div class="phone_number_div">
            <p class="phone_number_digits">(407)-242-2433</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= yield %>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-8">
          <img class="venus_freeze_footer" src="/assets/venusFreezeIcon.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application'%>
  </body>
</html>
```

**application.css**

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */


/*Mobile*/

body {
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.default_headers {
  font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
}

.js-menu-dd-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
}

.js-menu-dd {
 background-color: #353535;
 display: none;
}

.nav-menu-dd-text {
 color: white;
 letter-spacing: 0.05em;
 margin-bottom: 1.5em;
 margin-left: 1em;
 display: inline-block;
}

.nav_row {
  background-color: #353535;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: -0.1em;
}

.nav_glyphicon {
  font-size: 8em;
  margin-top: 0.3em;
  color: white;
}

.nav_text {
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

.border_under_nav {
  height: 0.5em;
  background-color: #424242;
  margin-top: -0.1em;
}

.main_logo_phone_number_row {
  margin-top: 6em;
}

.application_page_main_logo {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.phone_number_div {
  background-color: grey;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

.phone_number_digits {
  padding-top: 0.1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-shadow: 0px 3px 7px black;
}

.venus_freeze_footer {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}





/*Tablet*/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

    .nav-menu-dd-text{
      font-size: 2.3em;
    }

    .nav_glyphicon {
      font-size: 4em;
      margin-top: 0.3em;
      color: white;
    }

    .nav_text {
      font-size: 2.3em;
    }

    .main_logo_phone_number_row {
      margin-top: 12em;
    }

    .phone_number_div{
      margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    }

    .phone_number_digits {
      text-shadow: 0px 0px 25px black;
      font-size: 2.3em;
    }
}







/*Desktop*/

@media (min-width: 992px) {

  .default_headers {
    font-size: 5em;
  }

  .glyphicon {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav-menu-dd-text{
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }

  .nav_text {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
  }

  .main_logo_phone_number_row {
    margin-top: 8em;
  }

  .phone_number_div{
    margin-bottom: 2em;
  }

  .phone_number_digits {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 25px black;
    font-size: 2em;
  }

}
```

Comment: 991px and 992px seems a weird value to me, check this out for common breakpoints: https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints

Comment: I thought so too but Bootstrap docs state: Extra small devices(phone): <768px; Small devices(tablet): >=768; Medium devices(desktop): >=992; Large devices(desktop): >=1200

Comment: Yes but these are your oen elements right I would give it a try, it never failed for me. You might want to do a little test with border:1px solid red and so on for other breakpoints but with each having different color, then resize browser and see what happens :)

Comment: I fear this may be an issue with my Chrome Dev-Tools environment. When I resize the screen with the mouse from the desktop viewport, the CSS displays correctly. Although, when I am in my Dev-Tools environment, the CSS is not responding. The only thing I can think to do is restart Chrome? Any suggestions? I tried your media-query sizes as well and it is the same.

Comment: No i think it has to do with your site, try to do the same thing on other website that is responsive. It will work. If not then indeed something might be wrong with chrome. Try to setup a simple clean site that is 100% responsive and see if that is working, if it works go back to your current site and test without loading any js and css files but only with your respons. css. This way you will find the location of your problem. Hard to help you, its up to you from here. Also 1 thing is important to have set the meta tag for max device width and scale. Just google it to see all available options

Comment: Wow, I didnt even realize my `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` tag was missing. Thank you that resolved the issue!

Comment: Already had that feeling but couldnt see it only: `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` anyway, try to avoid that silly 991px / 992px. I think its weird xd